# fluent nhibernate r1.0 fluent mapping disable lazy load

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

how to disable lazy loading in fn r1.0?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(
       SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
       .InMemory)
       .Mappings( m => m.AutoMappings
           .Add( AutoMap.AssemblyOf<_Field>() ) )
       .Conventions
           .Add( FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never() )
       .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there's 8 left-parens here, and 7 right-parens here.

Answer (score 15):

You can try with:

```
Not.LazyLoad();
```

inside your mapping constructor.

Comment: it worked for me. I wanted an object reference to be loaded with the object and this did it.

Comment: It worked for us also. Our mapping has something like: HasMany(e => e.Children).KeyColumnNames.Add("ParentId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
References(x => x.Something).Not.LazyLoad();
```