# Prevent mapping all public members of a class in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class generated from a WSDL that has a bunch of public properties and a public event. I'm extending this class with my own and adding some properties to it. All of my own properties are declared `virtual`, but the base class properties are not virtual.

I'm using Fluent NHibernate's ClassMap to map only the properties from my extended class. How do I prevent (Fluent)NHibernate from trying to persist all the base class's public members?

At the moment, I get the following exception when creating the ISessionFactory:

> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
>
> Type: method get_`<BaseClassProperty`> should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
>
> Type: method set_`<BaseClassProperty`> should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
>
> ...
>
> Type: method add_`<BaseClassEvent`> should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
>
> Type: method remove_`<BaseClassEvent`> should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is not trying to persist all your public members. It's the NHibernate proxying mechanism that requires **all** members to be virtual; they may or may not be used for persistence, but they're needed anyway.

You either need to disable lazy-loading and proxying for the entity, or (preferably!) expose a DTO in your WS rather than the entity directly.

Comment: I'm not the author of the WS, so I can't change anything from that end. Looks like I'll have to disable lazy-loading. Thanks.

Comment: Is it correct to disable lazy-loading just for that entity by calling `Not.LazyLoad()` in the constructor of the ClassMap? Or is there a better way to do this? There seems to be a few ways to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412002/fluent-nhibernate-r1-0-fluent-mapping-disable-lazy-load

Comment: `Not.LazyLoad()` in the `ClassMap` is the easiest way to go if it's only particular entities that need it doing; if it's everything, you should look into a convention (one of the answers in that question you linked to uses the `DefaultLazy` convention).